# does $\int_0^{\infty} e^{(-t^2 -1/t^{2})} $ exists as improper riemann integral or lebesgue integral

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

> $\int_0^{\infty} e^{(-t^2 -1/t^{2})} $ dt

This question is from Apostol's mathematical analysis and the author has given many questions of this type in exercises of Ch-10 . I have done many of them but this is 1 of the question which I was not able to solve.

I used the defination of 10.32 for improper riemann integral and theorem 10.33 for lebesgue integral in most of the questions along with comparison tests for reimann integral but in this question I was not able to use any of the above bcoz of the type of function in the integrand.

So, I need help in how to approach this question.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the last term correct? Because then you just get $e^{-2t^2}$ in the exponent

Comment: It exists as both since $|e^{-(t^2+\tfrac{1}{t^2})}|\leq e^{-t^2}$.

Answer (score 2):

I will prove it is Lebesgue integrable. Clearly your issue is near $0$, since by comparison with $e^{-t^2}$ you can integrate it on $(\epsilon, \infty)$ for any $\epsilon > 0$ so we will focus on integrating on $(0,1)$.

Using the substitution $s = 1/t$ you get

$$ \int_{0}^1 e^{-t^2 -1/t^2}dt = \int_{1}^{\infty} e^{-s^2 - 1/s^2} s^{-2} ds $$

And now just use comparison test with $e^{-s^2}$.

Comment: Almost, except the last integrand should have $\frac{ds}{s^2}$. But the same argument holds after that (even more easily, actually, you don't have to find a dominating constant and you can just use the Gaussian directly)

Comment: @NinadMunshi Thank you. I make that mistake every time I apply substitution

Comment: The question is asking about $e^{-t^2-1/t^{-2}}$. If you think the OP meant to ask a different question, why wouldn't you clear that up with him before answering?

Comment: @marlasca23 Can you also help with riemann integral?